# How do I get the class of each ul>li item as a serial string?

Tags: jquery

**I'm trying to the get the class of each item in an unordered list, and turn it into a serialised string** that can be sent back as an AJAX call.

After a day's messing around with jQuery (that I like but am not very familiar with - seems so much harder than server-side stuff) am still no further. Can anyone provide some pointers?

So something like

```
<ul>
    <li class="expanded">Some text</li>
    <li class="expanded">Some text</li>
    <li>Some text</li>
    <li>Some text</li>
    <li class="expanded">Some text</li>
</ul>
```

would result in a string like

```
1,1,0,0,1
```

which is easily storable and parsable.

---

What I'm ultimately trying to do is to create an expandable list with the following characteristics:

- Clicking on an entry unhides a div
- Multiple items can be open at once, i.e. not an accordian system
- Maintains state, preferably via an Ajax call when a change is made, but client-side cookie is acceptable (e.g. would send a string like '0,1,1,0,0' meaning items 2&3 are open).

I've been using the excellent example #3 at

http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-3/ as documented at

http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/archive/2010/02/27/yup_yet_another_jquery_accordi

The author says "you can control the state of your accordions by having your page generation code set this class" but **sadly provides no pointers how to get the state out**.

Can anyone suggest a **postential strategy** of how to do this?

I've tried to loop through each item to get the class, with a view to serialising the list of item indexes - I thought something like

```
var target = $('ul.menu > li.active');
$.each(target, function(index, attributes) {
    alert(attributes.attr('class'));
});
```

might be a start, but hours trying different things aren't even getting me that far - just listing the current state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
var status = $('ul > li').map(function() {
     return +$(this).hasClass('expanded');
}).get().join(',');
```

This will create an array of `0`s and `1`s and joins it with `,` to create a string.

Note: I use an unary `+` to convert `true` and `false` to their numerical representations `1` and `0`.

**Reference:** [`jQuery.fn.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), [`jQuery.fn.hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/), [`jQuery.fn.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/), [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Nice use of +, but +1 regardless

Comment: Thanks - that is really excellent and makes a lot of sense. Hopefully my jQuery knowledge will catch up with my server-side knowledge some day!